# get foreground mask with OpenCV

Tags: opencv, image-segmentation, background-foreground

BackgroundSubtractorMOG2 returns a contour of the foreground not a mask. How to obtain a proper mask of a foreground using OpenCV?

Thanks,
Sajid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the foreground mask obtained there is 8bit, your captured image is probabably 24bit(3channels). so, to apply it on your actual image , you need to convert the mask to 3 channels as well:

```
Mat maskrgb;
cvtColor(mask,maskrgb,CV_GRAY2BGR);
// now , apply it:
Mat draw = imagergb & (maskrgb > 0);
imshow("lalala", draw );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use cv::fillPoly function with the input is the contour then you will have the mask.
http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/core/basic_geometric_drawing/basic_geometric_drawing.html